# How to use JQuery index() method

Tags: jquery

What am I missing regarding JQuery's index() method.  Based on the documentation, I would expect to be alerted a value of `1` here:

HTML

```
<div class="test" id="div1"></div>
<div class="test" id="div2"></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var index = $('.test').index('#div2');
    alert(index);
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cpody1cb/

Why am I alerted `-1`? If I instead use `index('#div1')`, I am alerted `0`, as I would expect.

Comment: you're selectors are backwards. `$('#div2').index('.test')`

Comment: The documentation says 'If we use a string as the .index() method's argument, it is interpreted as a jQuery selector string. The first element among the object's matched elements which also matches this selector is located.' I still don't understand why what I'm doing doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying too hard.

```
var index = $('#div2').index();
```

To explain why yours doesn't work, you simply have the selectors backward. The argument for the `index()` method should be a selector that gets the set of elements, not the element for which you want the index. This would be done like so:

```
var index = $('#div2').index('.test');
```

Comment: Are you sure that he wants index of element in page and not index in selection?

Comment: I want the index in a selection, not on page.

Comment: Based on the documentation I still don't understand why what I'm doing doesn't work.  It says "If we use a string as the .index() method's argument, it is interpreted as a jQuery selector string. The first element among the object's matched elements which also matches this selector is located."

Comment: the jquery docs actually says the opposite , I see why OP is confused , look from docs :   var index = $("div").index(this);    this meaning the element clicked.  "div"  is the collection , and this is the specific one to get the index of

Comment: Yes, exactly @ScottSelby. Any idea what I should do here? Is it just a bug in the documentation?

Comment: @flyingL123 - personally I have never needed .index()  ever , and I have made many many many sites with complex jquery .  So personally I would recommend to not use it , because this looks like a bug in the docs , or in the code and it may be changed some day.  There are so many other ways to accomplish whatever you need the index for

Answer (score 0):

Since the indexes are zero-based you should get `1`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var index = $('.test').index( $('#div2') );
    alert(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" id="div1"></div>
<div class="test" id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.index() can only work on one element, so it starts by reducing the set of selected elements to only the first one, which explains why you get `0` when you use `#div1` and `-1` when you use `#div2`. You should be selecting the div you want the index of, and then giving it a selector to tell it where to look for the element.

```
$('#div2').index('.test')
```

Comment: That is not the way it is explained in the doc's , I see why OP is confused they say var index = $("li").index(listItemClicked)  , so "li" is the collection , and itemClicked is the element you want the index of , your example works , but it opposite the way the offical docs say to do it